# Transaction in laravel eloquent query with multiple insert queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to know how to use transaction query to rollback if my queries have errors and commit if not. I have queries that use `foreach` cause of having multiple data. here's what I'm trying.

```
DB::transaction(function(){
                $receiving = New Table1;
                $receiving->created_on = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
                $receiving->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
                $receiving->received_on = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->DateAcquired);
                $receiving->received_by = Auth::user()->id;
                $receiving->checked_on = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
                $receiving->checked_by = Auth::user()->id;
                $receiving->remark = $request->Remarks;
                $receiving->save();

                foreach ($request->data as $data)
                {
                    $asset = New Table2;
                    $asset->category = $data[0];
                    /*$asset->asset_number = $data[1];*/
                    $asset->name = $data[2];
                    $asset->brand = $data[3];
                    $asset->model = $data[4];
                    $asset->ownership_type = $data[5];
                    $asset->serial_number = $data[6];
                    $asset->mac_address = $data[7];
                    $asset->cpu = $data[8];
                    $asset->memory = $data[9];
                    $asset->hard_disk = $data[10];
                    $asset->os = $data[11];
                    $asset->remark = $data[12];
                    $asset->description = $data[13];
                    $asset->date_acquired = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->DateAcquired);
                    $asset->receiving_id = $receiving->id;
                    $asset->save();
                }
            });
```

I also tried using `DB::beginTransaction();`

but I'm getting an error of

> undefined beginTransaction() function in query builder.

Comment: Did you added the use DB; ?

Comment: yes I already did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Laravel Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions):

> You may use the transaction method on the DB facade to run a set of
>   operations within a database transaction. If an exception is thrown
>   within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be
>   rolled back. If the Closure executes successfully, the transaction
>   will automatically be committed. You don't need to worry about
>   manually rolling back or committing while using the transaction
>   method:

but as I can see in your code that you are using `$request` variable within the callback function of `transaction`, so at this point, you should pass the `$request` to the callback function to use it.

your code will like below:

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {

               // put your code here  

 });
```

Comment: How can I put a error message if an error has occured?

Comment: And another thing your answer works the query will rollback but the incremented id still occured and added +1 is there possible way to avoid also that?

Comment: to put an error, you should catch Throwable, about the incremented id is not transactional as I know

Comment: Should I put the catch throwable inside the transaction function or outside?

Comment: Can I save a reference of DB::transaction? and when someone press "confirm" for each transactions saved, do a commit. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to pass your variable to the transaction via `use()`

```
  DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {
                    $receiving = New Table1;
                    $receiving->created_on = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
                    $receiving->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
                    $receiving->received_on = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->DateAcquired);
                    $receiving->received_by = Auth::user()->id;
                    $receiving->checked_on = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
                    $receiving->checked_by = Auth::user()->id;
                    $receiving->remark = $request->Remarks;
                    $receiving->save();

                    foreach ($request->data as $data)
                    {
                        $asset = New Table2;
                        $asset->category = $data[0];
                        /*$asset->asset_number = $data[1];*/
                        $asset->name = $data[2];
                        $asset->brand = $data[3];
                        $asset->model = $data[4];
                        $asset->ownership_type = $data[5];
                        $asset->serial_number = $data[6];
                        $asset->mac_address = $data[7];
                        $asset->cpu = $data[8];
                        $asset->memory = $data[9];
                        $asset->hard_disk = $data[10];
                        $asset->os = $data[11];
                        $asset->remark = $data[12];
                        $asset->description = $data[13];
                        $asset->date_acquired = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->DateAcquired);
                        $asset->receiving_id = $receiving->id;
                        $asset->save();
                    }
                });
```